# Android studio theme color change

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change the black portion to the default white color,How i fix it ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can find this settings here, select default theme:

[image: Theme settings]

I hope that help you

EDIT:

and here?

[image]

Comment: your method only change the white portion.